# Updating Model Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attr-accessible

I have a Rails app that is a blogging platform, allowing for multiple contributing authors.  My **User** model has a **:writer** boolean attribute for assigning writing permissions.  However, **:writer** is NOT listed under **attr_accessible** for the **User** model.

I wanted to a way to edit this attribute through the web, without having to run

```
User.find_by_id(user_id).update_attribute(:writer, true/false)
```

through the console, but I'm wondering if this would be impossible without listing **:writer** under **attr_accessible** for the **User** model. I have several pages accessible only to admin-users, and I would like to be able to put the ability to toggle the **:writer** attribute within those views.

If it is indeed possible, how could it be done? Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit:** Based on the couple of answers I've gotten, I feel should've been more specific in my question.  I apologize.  I understand that I could still individually update the **:writer** attribute, as Beerlington and Hitesh have pointed out.  What I wanted to know was how one could implement such a function through the view.  Would it be possible to make a clickable link to toggle the :writer state?  Might it be possible to have a link call a controller function and pass the appropriate **user_id** for **:writer** toggling?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

attr_accessible and attr_protected only protect attributes from [mass-assignment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment). You can still assign them through other means though:

Mass Assignment (will not work):

```
model.update_attributes(:admin => true)
```

Non Mass Assignment (option 1):

```
model.admin = boolean
model.save
```

Non Mass Assignment (option 2):

```
model.send(:attributes=, attributes, false)
```

Non Mass Assignment (option 3):

```
model.update_attribute(admin, boolean)
```

I personally do not like either of these manual options, so I wrote a gem called [sudo_attributes](https://github.com/beerlington/sudo_attributes) that makes it easier to override mass assignment using "sudo" methods.

Comment: Thanks Beerlington!  Is there a way to implement any of these options through the view, perhaps through a button or clickable link?

Comment: This could couldn't be in the view and would have to be in either your controller or model.

Comment: If I were to create a method to do this called, say, toggle_writer, in my controller, could _that_ be called through a button or clickable link?

Comment: Yea you could definitely do that. There are a dozen ways you could do it though. If you're still unsure, I'd recommend creating another question and someone could give you help.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
User.find_by_id(user_id).update_attribute(:writer, true) or 
User.find_by_id(user_id).update_attribute(:writer, false)
```